# Using Moustache as a templating language in Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, mustache

I'm starting to use symfony 2 but I'd like to use moustache as the templating language instead of Twig or PHP. I wan't to use moustache because it's totally logicless and because I can also use it in javascript if I decide to handle the rendering of the template clientside.

How to do that?

Comment: I've been meaning to finish this for a while... https://github.com/bobthecow/BobthecowMustacheBundle Feel free to fork and help out.

Comment: @bobthecow i forked it, i'm fairly new to symfony2 and i think i will take some time to understand everything, expecially since this is done in my spare time, in any case thank you! :)

Comment: As of the latest commit, my bundle works with Symfony2 v2.1.0-DEV :)

Comment: You can also try this bundle: https://github.com/BeSimple/BeSimpleMustacheBundle

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Some extra info extending @m2mdas answer.

If you are not yet familiar with Symfony templating systems and bundle configuration take a look at these before you start coding:

- [How to expose a Semantic Configuration for a Bundle](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html)
- [Creating and using Templates](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/templating.html)
- [How to use PHP instead of Twig for Templates](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/templating/PHP.html)

And now a quick recipe to get you started. Take the following as loose examples, no need to stick with the names choosed.

**1. Create a `Resources/config/mustache.xml` to define your services and to identify your template engine service (tag it as `"templating.engine"`).**

*You could use Yaml and PHP instead of XML but the latter is prefered for "public" bundles.*

```xml
<service id="mustache" class="Mustache">
    <file>Mustache.php</file>
</service>

<service id="templating.engine.mustache" class="MustacheBundle\MustacheEngine" public="false">
        <argument type="service" id="mustache" />
        <argument type="service" id="templating.name_parser"/>
        <argument type="service" id="templating.loader" />
        <tag name="templating.engine" />
</service>
```

Examples:

- [Twig](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/Resources/config/twig.xml)
- [PHP](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/templating_php.xml)
- [Smarty](https://github.com/noiselabs/SmartyBundle/blob/master/Resources/config/smarty.xml)

**2. Create an `Extension` class to handle the semantic configuration for your bundle.**

```
<?php

namespace MustacheBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\Extension;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\Loader\XmlFileLoader;

class MustacheExtension extends Extension
{
    $loader = new XmlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
    $loader->load('mustache.xml');

    // you may parse the $configs array here
    // see: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html#parsing-the-configs-array
}
```

The presence of the previous class means that you can now define a `mustache` configuration namespace in any configuration file.

Examples:

- [Twig](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/DependencyInjection/TwigExtension.php)
- [Smarty](https://github.com/noiselabs/SmartyBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/SmartyExtension.php)

**3. *[Optional]* Create a `Configuration` class to validate and merge configuration**

```
<?php

namespace Mustache\DependencyInjection;

use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\Builder\TreeBuilder;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Definition\ConfigurationInterface;

class Configuration implements ConfigurationInterface
{
    public function getConfigTreeBuilder()
    {
        $treeBuilder = new TreeBuilder();
        $rootNode = $treeBuilder->root('mustache');

        // see: http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/bundles/extension.html#validation-and-merging-with-a-configuration-class
    }
}
```

Examples:

- [Twig](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php)
- [Smarty](https://github.com/noiselabs/SmartyBundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php)

**4. Create a `MustacheEngine` that implements [EngineInterface](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Templating/EngineInterface.php)**

```php
<?php

namespace MustacheBundle;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Templating\EngineInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Templating\TemplateNameParserInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Templating\Loader\LoaderInterface;

use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class MustacheBundle implements EngineInterface
{
    public function __construct(\Mustache $mustache, TemplateNameParserInterface $parser, LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $this->mustache = $mustache;
        $this->parser = $parser;
    }

    public function render($name, array $parameters = array())
    {
        $template = $this->load($name);

        return $this->mustache->render($template);
    }

    // Renders a view and returns a Response.
    public function renderResponse($view, array $parameters = array(), Response $response = null)
    {
        if (null === $response) {
            $response = new Response();
        }

        $response->setContent($this->render($view, $parameters));

        return $response;
    }

    // Returns true if the template exists.
    public function exists($name)
    {
        try {
            $this->load($name);
        } catch (\InvalidArgumentException $e) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }

    // Returns true if this class is able to render the given template.
    public function supports($name)
    {
        $template = $this->parser->parse($name);

        return 'mustache' === $template->get('engine');
    }

    // Loads the given template.
    // Should return the template name or a Mustache template object
    protected function load($name)
    {
        $template = $this->parser->parse($name);
        $template = $this->loader->load($template);

        return (string) $template;
    }
```

Examples:

- [Twig](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/TwigBundle/TwigEngine.php)
- [PHP](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Templating/PhpEngine.php)
- [Smarty](https://github.com/noiselabs/SmartyBundle/blob/master/SmartyEngine.php)

**5. Enable your shiny new template engine in the application configuration file:**

```
# app/config/config.yml
templating:    { engines: ['twig', 'mustache'] }
```

**6. Try it**

```
<?php
// src/Acme/HelloBundle/Controller/HelloController.php

public function indexAction($name)
{
    return $this->render('AcmeHelloBundle:Hello:index.html.mustache', array('name' => $name));
}
```

You may share a link to your bundle repository so we can track progress and help if needed. Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, this is a really good answer, i'll post  the code as soon as i write some (i'm using simfony2 for my personal projects!) :)

Comment: noisebleed: great writeup. it helped a ton :) — https://github.com/bobthecow/BobthecowMustacheBundle

Answer (score 5):

You have to create a class that implements [EngineInterface](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Templating/EngineInterface.php) and create create a DIC service named `templating.engine.mustache` to reference the class. And then in `app/config.yml` you can set default engine.

```
#app/config.yml
framework:
  #.....
  templating:
      engines: ['mustache'] //mustache is the last portion of the service id
```

For reference you can check [PhpEngine](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Templating/PhpEngine.php) class and its [service definition](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/master/src/Symfony/Bundle/FrameworkBundle/Resources/config/templating_php.xml#L25).

Comment: This. I've got one 80% finished... I can publish it if you wanna play around :)