# How create config in symfony2 for mustache like twig config

Tags: php, symfony, mustache

I create config for twig

```
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    paths:
            "%kernel.root_dir%/../../web/admin": admin_templates
            "%kernel.root_dir%/../../web": templates
```

And use admin_templates in render function

```
return $this->render('@admin_templates/hello.html.twig');
```

I want create config for mustache and use

```
return $this->render('@admin_templates/hello.html.mustache');
```

How create valid config for mustache in symfony2?

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965421/using-moustache-as-a-templating-languange-in-symfony-2

Comment: it's not what i need