# How to use Mustache in Twig templates? They both have the same tag delimiters

Tags: twig, mustache

I use Twig in my project. It uses these tags: `{{ name }}`

I want to include Mustache in my project as well. But Mustache also uses the same tags `{{ name }}`, so there is a conflict and nothing works.

The solution Mustache provides in their docs of course doesn't work. Because I have to type Twig delimiter `{{` in my Twig template to change Mustache delimiter.

```
* {{ default_tags }}
{{=<% %>=}}
* <% erb_style_tags %>
<%={{ }}=%>
* {{ default_tags_again }}
```

How to pass over it? Is there any other way to change Mustache delimiters once somewhere in settings?

Comment: Rather than having twig and mustache together. Would it be worth replacing Twig - [Using Moustache as a templating languange in Symfony 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965421/using-moustache-as-a-templating-languange-in-symfony-2)?

Comment: It sounds like "I don't like a table lamp in my room. Then would it be worth replacing your house to get rid of the lamp?" I do not use Symphony2, only Twig.

Comment: Sorry, i misunderstood and made some 'less than useful' assumptions.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a large template to pass through twig. A better solution is to temporarily turn off autoescape.

```
{% verbatim %}
    Everything will be outputted as is in this block
{% endverbatim %}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can customize twig delimiters to be differents than Mustache ones by replacing `{{` and `}}` by `[[` and `]]` for example, as explained [in Twig doc](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/recipes.html#customizing-the-syntax):

```
$twig = new Twig_Environment();

$lexer = new Twig_Lexer($twig, array(
    'tag_comment'   => array('{#', '#}'),
    'tag_block'     => array('{%', '%}'),
    'tag_variable'  => array('[[', ']]'),
    'interpolation' => array('#{', '}'),
));
$twig->setLexer($lexer);
```

Answer (score 1):

Workaround is to "echo" double brackets with twig

```
{{ "{{some_js_varaible}}" }}
```

and

```
{{ "{% js_condition %}" }}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'{% verbatim %}
<a href="{{joblink}}" target="_blank">{{{_highlightResult.title.value}}}</a><p>{{description}}</p>
{% endverbatim %}'
```

Explanation:

- {% verbatim %} tells twig not interpret {{some content}} as twig
- html syntax remains the same such as link
- so if your code/function/config expect Mustache string, there you have it: {{Mustache.object.value}}.

From source:

https://github.com/janl/mustache.js/issues/441

Tested working in Symfony framework.