# Handlebars/Mustache with Symfony/PHP7

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, handlebars.js

I am trying to work with handlebar templates, but it's not going so well.

In *.html.twig I have:

```
<script id="entry-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
    <div class="entry">
        <h1>{{title}}</h1>
        <div class="body">
            {{body}}
        </div>
    </div>
</script>

<span id="demo">
</span>

<script>
    var source   = document.getElementById("entry-template").innerHTML;
    var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
    var context = {title: "My New Post", body: "This is my first post!"};
    var html    = template(context);
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = html;    
</script>
```

And there is an error:

> Variable "title" does not exist.

When I put this code in simple index.html w/o Symfony etc. it works. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Mustache in Twig templates? They both have the same tag delimiters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29509827/how-to-use-mustache-in-twig-templates-they-both-have-the-same-tag-delimiters)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is happening because Twig is also an HTML templating language which also uses `{{ ... }}` syntax to denote variables, just like Mustache is, so Twig is trying to parse it before outputting the HTML.

If you want to use Twig and Mustache together, then you'll need to escape/double-encode the curly braces that are intended for Mustache so that Twig doesn't try to parse them first.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [repo on Github](https://github.com/jonschlinkert/handlebars-delimiters) which lets you define your own custom delimiters for Handlebar templates.