# Symfony2 error: The service "templating" has a dependency on a non-existent service "templating.globals"

Tags: php, symfony, templates

I have just installed a bundle using the following command to activate Mustache templates in my project but now I get the following error;

The service "templating" has a dependency on a non-existent service "templating.globals".

The command I used was:

composer.phar require bobthecow/mustache-bundle

Of course I know I am missing the templating.globals service but How do I include this and why is it not included automatically?

Comment: Did you register the bundle in AppKernel.php?

Comment: Yes I did. I added: new Bobthecow\Bundle\MustacheBundle\BobthecowMustacheBundle(),

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9965421/3008172 this one should bring the answer.

Comment: This bundle does this for me: https://github.com/bobthecow/BobthecowMustacheBundle

Comment: have you registered mustache in the template engines config ? https://github.com/bobthecow/BobthecowMustacheBundle#configyml

Comment: Yes, I have rigestered it.

Answer (score 27):

The `templating.globals` service is only created by the `symfony/framework-bundle` if you have `php` in the list on templating engines.

As you can see in the [`Resources/config/templating_php.xml`](https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle/blob/master/Resources/config/templating_php.xml#L78-L80) the service is created.

This file is only loaded in the extension if [`php` is in the list of templating engines](https://github.com/symfony/framework-bundle/blob/master/DependencyInjection/FrameworkExtension.php#L522-L523).

**TL;DR** Add `php` to the templating engines in your `app/config/config.yml`.

```
# app/config/config.yml
framework:
    # ...
    templating:
        engines: ['twig', 'php']
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks this was helpful. Is it possible to render a string instead of a template. I want to pass a string into the render

Comment: You can use `template_from_string` ( http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/template_from_string.html ) but I'm not sure how you would go about it with this set up.

Comment: Can't I add my own method/extension/class to the BobthecowMustacheBundle and call the same way I called the render. Except new render will accept a string instead of a file. I am sure I am add this somewhere in the bundle like an extension.

Comment: Maybe, although you shouldn't add anything to the actual bundle but an extension of the bundle.

Comment: Note: This is still valid for Symfony 4, edit `config\packages\framework.yaml`

Answer (score 1):

If you are running **Symfony 4.x** then You've to add the following to the config/packages/framework.yaml:

```
framework:
    # ... other stuff ...

    templating:
        engines: ['twig', 'php']
```